# how to write code for find index of element in subset?

Tags: r

```
library(gRbase)     
m<-combn(1:4,2,simplify=FALSE)
m

[[1]]

[1] 1 2

[[2]]

[1] 1 3

[[3]]

[1] 1 4


[[4]]

[1] 2 3

[[5]]

[1] 2 4

[[6]]

[1] 3 4
```

I want output for element 2 fn(2):1,4,5

Comment: How about `grep("2", m)`  What's the package being loaded for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res <- vector("numeric"); for( i in seq_along(m)){ if(2 %in% m[[i]]){res<-c(res,i)}}

>res
[1] 1 4 5
```

To encapsulate in a function:

```
 fn <- function(lis , item){
      res <- vector("numeric")
  for( i in seq_along(m)){ if(2 %in% m[[i]]){res<-c(res,i)}}
 res}

> fn(m,item)
[1] 1 4 5
```

Here's another methos which seems less obvious to me: I'm posting the sequence of intermediate steps I used to get there:

```
 sapply(seq_along(m),function(x) match(x=2,m[[x]]) )
#[1]  2 NA NA  1  1 NA
 as.logical(sapply(seq_along(m),function(x) match(x=2,m[[x]]) )  )
#[1] TRUE   NA   NA TRUE TRUE   NA
 which(as.logical(sapply(seq_along(m),function(x) match(x=2,m[[x]]) ) )  )
#[1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: In this case you don't know the length of the result in advance so the less efficient serial extension strategy is needed.

Comment: It could be done with a list, but I'm not sure that's any better/more efficient `v <- vector("list", length(m)); for(i in seq_along(m)) { v[[i]] <- if(2 %in% m[[i]]) i else NULL } ; unlist(v)`

Comment: Your strategy might allow an 'lapply' approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
which(vapply(m, function(x) 2 %in% x, FUN.VALUE = FALSE))
#[1] 1 4 5
```

Comment: Also `fn <- function(i) which(sapply(m,"%in%",x=i))`, which is basically the same thing.